# How to get current page title and add it to link directly as variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, hyperlink

Am trying to create a facebook share code in just html and javascript
I would want the link to be exactly like this:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://lmn.9nty.com/?t=PAGETITLE+++-+learnmorenigeria+website%26l=www.learnmoreng.com/site_responcepage.html"> share </a>
```

But the problem now is, how can I get the page title through the help of ONLY javascript and then add it to the link at t=PAGETITLE.

Comment: Don't "SHOUT" ... it is bad manners.

Comment: you can use document.title.

Comment: To get the current title and add it as a varible in href=""

Comment: @ReubenOdunmbaku You just want to get the current page title and add it as a query string parameter to the link with JS, right? If so, I think my answer will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want to append a "?t=" parameter to the query string passed into the FB share link with the `document.title`. If that is correct, you can do

```
var shareURL = fbShareURL + encodeURIComponent(linkURL + "?t=" + document.title));
```

which will make a URL like

> https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Flmn.9nty.com%2F%3Ft%3DTITLE

which will include the page title as a query string parameter in url-encoded form. It's up to you what you do with that query string parameter, though. Using jQuery, you can update the share link dynamically:

```
var fbShareURL = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=";
var title = document.title; // The current page
var linkURL = "http://lmn.9nty.com/";

$link = $("<a>");
$link.attr("href", fbShareURL + encodeURIComponent(linkURL + "?t=" + title));
$link.text("Share");

// Add the link to your page
$("body").append($link);
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/7wst45gq/1/

---

Here is full, working HTML code as requested:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>How to get current page title and add it to link directly as variable in JavaScript</title>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
    $(window).load(function(){

    // Begin demo code
    var fbShareURL = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=";
    var title = document.title; // The current page
    var linkURL = "http://lmn.9nty.com/";

    $link = $("<a>");
    $link.attr("href", fbShareURL + encodeURIComponent(linkURL + "?t=" + title));
    $link.text("Share");

    // Add the link to your page
    $("body").append($link);
    // End demo code

    });//]]>
  </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried to post a snippet, but StackOverflow intentionally blocks Facebook links, even in example. Apologies. How else can I help? Did you see my demo link?

Comment: I saw it, but couldnt copy it out, you can help me with the full code by posting it here: http://www.learnmoreng.com/forum2_theme_111582926.xhtml?tema=3

Comment: Hello, I've updated my answer to include a complete HTML source

Comment: Thanks soo much but the problem now is its appending after my footer, can i make it append to my desired part in the body only?

Comment: Yes. Replace `$("body")` with the jQuery selector of your footer element. For example, if your footer is like `<div id="footer"></div>`, then change `$("body")` to `$("#footer")`.

Comment: One last question, how can i replace the text Share with this image: http://w.sharethis.com/images/facebook_counter.png

Comment: Replace `$link.text("Share");` with `$link.html("<img src=\"http://w.sharethis.com/images/facebook_counter.png\">");`

Comment: Thanks for your lot of help Drakes
But this worked instead
        $link.html("<img src=http://w.sharethis.com/images/facebook_counter.png>");
You are a genius.

Answer (score 1):

`sharer.php` only takes the URL as parameter, the rest of the data will come from the [Open Graph tags](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/object-properties):

```
a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://lmn.9nty.com/">Share</a>
```

Btw, you should [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) the shared URL.

Comment: I know of that @Luschn, what i dont know is if javascript can import the page title to href="" . Thanks for your response.

Comment: no, that´s not possible, which is exactly what i was trying to tell you in my answer. you can ONLY use the url as parameter.

Comment: I still believe its possible, since i am able to share self generated title from my forum and url in my own builtup code, then i think its possible to pass the page title instead of the static title one.

Comment: no, sharer.php only takes the title from og:title. that is a fact ;)